# How to update one table by joining two table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got two tables one is for regcourses and another is named coursegroups.

**coursegroups table**

```
CREATE TABLE coursesgroup (
  csgrec int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  courseID int(11) default NULL,
  classID int(11) default NULL,
  studgroup varchar(20) default NULL,
  studnum int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (csgrec)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

***regcourses table:***

```
CREATE TABLE regcourses (
  regrec int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  regsemrec int(11) default NULL,
  regstudID int(11) default NULL,
  regcourseID int(11) default NULL,
  regstatus int(11) default '0',
  yearsem int(11) default '2012',
  monthsem1 int(11) default '3',
  classID int(11) default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (regrec)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Insert statement:**

```
INSERT INTO coursesgroup VALUES ('2', '20', '1', 'BBA1009A1', '11');
INSERT INTO coursesgroup VALUES ('3', '20', '1', 'BBA1009B1', '4');

INSERT INTO regcourses VALUES ('2', '1', '98', '47', '0', '2012', '3', '1');
INSERT INTO regcourses VALUES ('4', '1', '98', '101', '0', '2012', '3', '1');
```

I want to update the regstatus field of regcourses table to "2" for a specific value of csgrec column in coursesgroup table. So my update code is:

```
UPDATE regcourses JOIN coursesgroup ON regcourses.regcourseID = coursesgroup.courseID 
Set regcourses.regstatus =2
WHERE  coursesgroup.csgrec=3
```

but my query is affecting so many rows instead of one row. Because I want to change the csgrec=3 only and my query affects all of the lines which matches with `regcourses.regcourseID = coursesgroup.courseID condition`. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

First, run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM regcourses
JOIN coursesgroup ON regcourses.regcourseID = coursesgroup.courseID 
WHERE  coursesgroup.csgrec=3
```

(That's basically the same as your update, without doing any updates.) That will tell you if your join is wrong; if you're matching too many rows.

From your `insert` statments, I can't see what is supposed to be happening -- from the four rows you've shown, nothing should match that join condition. Try the insert and see how many rows are returned first.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I've shown only 4 rows here but there are several more insert lines. which has common courseID in it. And I've tried the Select query with group by clause and its working just like I need. the query is: SELECT * FROM regcourses 
WHERE regcourseID =(SELECT courseID FROM coursesgroup WHERE csgrec=3) 
GROUP BY regcourseID

but I want to use the group by clause in update also. How can I use the group by clause on update?

Comment: Why do you need the `GROUP BY`? That might be hiding something from you. That will force your select to only return one row for each regcourseid, even if there are multiple rows in the database.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion also and it is retrieving so many output row instead of 1 row. because for csgrec field there is only one '3'. But still I'm getting so many rows. How can I get only one row without using group by?

Comment: If there are multiple regcourse rows that have the same courseid, and you only want to update one of them, then the question to ask is "how do you know which one to update?" Can you say that it is a row with a specific status? or a specific student id?

Comment: yes actually all regstatus is now 0 or 1 but it has to be 2 where the csgrec=3 or some specific value. I mean in my program I will take the csgrec from the user and it can be any value from 1 to 5000 almost and by matching the user input with the csgrec field the regstatus will be changed to 2 from 0 or 1.